# How to share object instance with input from consuming application?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Right now, I've got this one big monolithic application.  But, my goal is to pull some of the code out, and put it in a separate git repository, and make a separate npm package.  And then this package would be consumed by the former monolithic code base.  And the same package would be consumed in other applications (eventually).

One of the ES6 classes that is a part of this (eventually) shared code takes a couple of constructor arguments:

```
export class Entitlement {
   //stuff
   constructor (entitlementsAliasMap: EntitlementsAliasMap, autoEnable: AutoEnableMap) {
     //constructor stuff
   }
   //lots more stuff
}
```

These two constructor arguments should come from the consuming application of the shared code.  Once these arguments are provided, I need to actually instantiate the class.  And I want to share an instance of that created class with other code (through ES6 imports) inside the shared set of code.

One way to do this (I think) would be through global variables.

In monolithic application:

```
let window.shared.entitlementsAliasMap = <stuff>
let window.shared.autoEnable = <other stuff>
import { Entitlement } from 'Entitlement';
```

In shared code, Entitlement.ts:

```
//lots of other stuff
export let entitlement = new Entitlement(window.shared.entitlementsAliasMap , window.shared.autoEnable);
```

Elsewhere in shared code, say Foo.ts

```
import { entitlement} from './entitlement/Entitlement';
```

Assuming this even works, it relies on some global variables.  Are there other ideas on how I can share an instance of an object across package boundaries like this, without using global variables? There is the requirement that the consuming application provides inputs to the shared code, which is critical for the object to be created.

If this were React code, I might be tempted to stuff things in context, and read it out of context.  But this is vanilla ES6 code that is running in a browser.  (I am using babel, typescript and webpack, for what it's worth).

UPDATE:

So, thanks to both @Antoine and @Bergi for their ideas.  I apologize if the question is still unclear.  Based on their feedback, I have a new idea that I believe is better than my earlier (awful) global variable approach.  Maybe it can be refined further.

The new idea is this. (Please forgive errors in typescript typing or JS; I haven't implemented this revised version yet). The shared code has a couple of files.

Entitlement.ts

```
export class Entitlement {
   //stuff
   constructor (entitlementsAliasMap: EntitlementsAliasMap, autoEnable: AutoEnableMap) {
     //constructor stuff
   }
   //lots more stuff
}

let instance: Entitlement;

export const getInstance() => {
    if (instance) {
        return instance;
    }
    else throw 'Not initialized';
}

export init(entitlementsAliasMap: EntitlementsAliasMap, autoEnable: AutoEnableMap) {
    if (instance) {
        throw 'Already initialized'; //or just do nothing
    }
    else {
        instance = new Entitlement(entitlementsAliasMap, autoEnable);
    }
}
```

Foo.ts

```
import { getInstance } from './entitlement/Entitlement';
//somewhere down below, in code that is not immediately executed
const entitlement = getInstance();
entitlement.<some method name>
```

And in the consuming/monolothic application, sometime near startup:

```
import { init, getInstance} from 'Entitlement';

let entitlementsAliasMap = <value>;
let autoEnable = <some other value>;

init(entitlementsAliasMap, autoEnable);

//later, as needed
const entitlement = getInstance();
entitlement.<some method name>
```

Would this revised approach be more reasonable?

Comment: I realize that you just need some ES6 code not a tool as you mentioned, but IMHO it's not a good idea to have a mutable object for global state.


You can use one of the following tools to achieve shared state without global variables, there is much more tools and it depends on your needs.

 - ReactN

 - Redux

 - React built-in context API. (Recommended for a package).


You can also use custom reactHooks that share a static instance but that should be your last resort.

Comment: Thanks Antoine, yeah things would be "easier" if this were React code, but it's not in this case. I don't really want to introduce the baggage of something like Redux for this use case.  I agree with your sentiment though - I feel kind of sick using global variables, but I haven't thought of anything better that is still lightweight and generic without dragging along an entire framework.

Answer (score 1):

### Warning this code contains bad practices

You don't have to initialize the instance from the package itself just from the main project. (Please use Singleton pattern)

package-name/Singleton.js

```
class Singleton {
  constructor (value1, value2) {
    if (!Singleton.instance) {
      Singleton.instance = this
      this.value1 = value1
      this.value2 = value2
    }
    return Singleton.instance
  }
}
```

Then use it like this in your project.

SingletonInstance.js

```
import { Singleton } from 'package-name/Singletone'
const instance = new Singleton(val1, val2)
export default instance
```

to use the instance at any part of another package by using

```
import { Singleton } from 'package-name/Singletone'
// Check for initialization before any call
if (Singleton.instance) {
  console.log(Singleton.value1); // should output 'value1';
}
```

IMHO after understanding what you need to this point it would be far easier to integrate a dependency injection framework or implement it by yourself, please let me know if you are interested in the comments.

I would also discourage you from using this as a state management.

Comment: I was thinking of the singleton pattern, but I've not seen it used with arguments.  I'm not sure how the factory pattern would be used here.  Could you please elaborate with some sample pseudo code, based on the example I gave above?

Comment: I added an example of using a Singleton without a factory for easiness sake.

Comment: Thanks for the sample! I see your suggestion now. The tricky part is I need the singleton instance not just in the monolithic/consuming application - I also need the instance in the shared code, in different spots (in this case Foo.ts. Foo.ts is in the library, not the monolithic application)

Comment: You can pass the instance to any package.
I will add an update.

Comment: I am a bit confused of what you are trying to accomplish, you can always pass an instance to different dependencies without them being static.

Comment: Yes, I think that might be the key - construct it outside (either directly through a constructor call or through a factory like method) and then have a second method to use that instance.  Sorry, I know this question is confusing.  I tried to make it clear, but I think I've failed in that regard.  I think I'll update the question with another idea I have (no global variables) inspired by both your and Bergi's feedback

Comment: I added a second answer please let me know if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

No, don't put the line

```
export let entitlement = new Entitlement(window.shared.entitlementsAliasMap , window.shared.autoEnable);
```

inside the library code. Have the library export the `Entitlement` constructor, let the application deal with instantiating it (once, or possibly multiple times - in tests or so) and sharing the instance(s).

The code of your monolithic application should have

```
// entitlement.js
import { Entitlement } from 'Entitlement'; // the library module
const entitlementsAliasMap = <stuff>;
const autoEnable = <other stuff>;
export const entitlement = new Entitlement(EntitlementsAliasMap, autoEnable);
```

and

```
// Foo.ts
import { entitlement } from './entitlement'; // the monolith module sharing the instance
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Bergi!  The tricky part is I need the entitlement instance not just in the monolithic/consuming application - I also need the instance in the shared code, in different spots (in this case Foo.ts.  Foo.ts is in the library, not the monolithic application).  The shared code cannot instantiate the class itself, because it doesn't have all the required information; that's only available in the consuming/monolothic class.

Comment: @Notre If the `Foo` is part of the library that defines the `Entitlement` constructor, then the foos that need the entitlement should either be part of it (so that they can be accessed through it and keep a reference) or they should be constructed by the monolithic application by passing a reference to the `entitlement`.

Comment: I think I follow what you're saying.  I also have an idea how to solve this now, based on ideas both you and Antoine presented.  I don't think there's enough space in a comment to describe it.  Not sure what the best approach is here -- add an answer of my own, or update the question with a new proposed answer.  Suggestions?

Comment: To my last comment, I think I'll update the question, posing a new idea inspired by your and Antoine's feedback.  Sorry, I realize the question isn't super clear; I tried, but I don't think I did a great job in that regard

Comment: I added as a revision to the question; I didn't want to take credit for your ideas :)  I will upvote both your answers

Comment: @Notre Thanks. Now that *is* just a singleton :-) Throwing on multiple `init` calls is absolutely necessary, unless the caller provides exactly the same arguments. The `init` should also `return` the new instance, in case the initialising application needs it. The `getInstance` I would avoid, especially within the library, you can just `export let instance = null;` and refer to that in the other modules directly (`import { instance } from '…'`).

Comment: It is _very_ much like a singleton, but it cannot be constructed inside the library, and yet it needs to be available there.  The ``getInstance`` idea was borrowed from the classic singleton solution (e.g. on wikipedia).  I like the getInstance function over exporting the instance field directly because the function allows me to throw an error if it hasn't been previously initialized by an ``init`` call.

Thank you _very much_ for thoughts, time, and guidance!

Comment: @Notre You can also use the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) where you don't initialised `instance` to `null` but to an object that has the same methods as a normal `Entitlement` but each of them throws when being called.

Comment: Makes sense, that's another interesting approach :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also borrow the idea of injectables with a very simple implementation like this.

shared-package/entitlement.ts

```
  export class Entitlement () {
    value1: string = ""
    value2: string = ""
    constructor(value1: string, value2: string) {
      this.value1 = value1
      this.value2 = value2
    }
  }
```

package1/foo.ts

```
import { Entitlement } from 'shared-package/entitlement'
export class Foo {
  constructor (entitlementInstance: Entitlement) {
    console.log(entitlementInstance.value1)
  }
}
```

package2/bar.ts

```
import { Entitlement } from 'shared-package/entitlement'
export class Bar {
  constructor (entitlementInstance: Entitlement) {
    console.log(entitlementInstance.value1)
  }
}
```

Finally in your application

```
import { Entitlement } from 'shared-package/entitlement'
import { Foo } from 'package-name1/foo'
import { Bar } from 'package-name2/bar'

const entitlement = new Entitlement('value1', 'value2')
const foo = new Foo(entitlement)
const bar = new Bar(entitlement)
```

Comment: Not sure I follow this.  It could be my ignorance (very likely) but it also could be I'm still failing to describe my use case clearly.  Please see my revised question, where I added an alternative implementation (inspired by your comments, although "bad" parts are all mine).  Does this seem better to you?

Comment: In my use case, I have two packages - the one big monolithic application and the shared library.  The shared library contains (among other things) the definition of the Entitlement class, and a second file (module) that consume an instance of the Entitlement class.  The assumption are that:
1. It's the same instance used throughout
2. Any shared library use of the instance would occur after the instance has been created by the consuming application
3. The shared library can't instantiate the Entitlement class itself, since it doesn't have all the necessary parameters

Comment: Your solution would work without any bad parts actually, this solution is just a very generic way to implement the same thing without any static instances.

Comment: Thanks Antoine for all the ideas, feedback and your time.  Much appreciated!